# Find sublist using pattern match

Tags: scala

I need to find sublist using pattern match, how can I do it?

```
val list1 = List(2, 3)
val list2 = List(1, "2", list1, "r")
val list3 = list2 match {
      case // insert match statement here
      case _ => "failed"
}

assertEquals(list1, list3)
```

I cannot change given code, I may insert code only here
`case // insert match statement here`
it is school task (not from work)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  What sublist do you want to find?  What is `list`?  Do you really mean to return the string "failed" if you can't find the sublist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Just `.find` for the first list. As you were not clear on which sublist you are looking for I just assumed the first one. Otherwise, you'd have to adjust the predicate used for the find-call.

```
val list1 = List(2, 3)
val list2 = List(1, "2", list1, "r")
val list3 = list2.find(_.isInstanceOf[List[_]]) match {
      case Some(listFound) => listFound
      case _ => "failed"
}

assertEquals(list1, list3) // true
```

### Another "solution":

The question is not clear enough. With a match statement, as Rex pointed out, you're not going to get far. To satisfy only the minimal example above (which may be all the homework requires), you may match the exact list. I.e. you can hardcode that you want exactly the third element of the list. In that case, you can write something like this:

```
case x :: y :: mylist :: rest => mylist
```

This makes next to no sense, but solves the required assert, so at best is an exercise to the usage of `::` for constructing lists.

Comment: I cannot change given code, I may insert code only here `case // insert match statement here` - it is school task (not from work)

Comment: Yes it is homework, but it is from job training, so I need to do my best :)

Comment: But your solution is better then `case head :: tail => if (head.isInstanceOf[List[_]]) head else tail.find(_.isInstanceOf[List[_]]).get`

Comment: You could also use the List extractor: `case List(a,b,c,d) => c`

Answer (score 4):

You don't want a *match*, you want a *find*:

```
list2.find(_ == list1)
```

will give you a `Some(List(2, 3))` (or a `None` if it can't be found).  To match your code exactly, you'd:

```
list2.find(_ == list1).getOrElse("failed")
```

though using `Option` rather than a possible string is a better way to handle error conditions.

If you really want to use a match, you have to do it recursively:

```
final def findOrFailed(xs: List[Any], what: Any): Any = xs match {
  case x :: rest => if (x == what) x else findOrFailed(rest,what)
  case _ => "failed"
}
```

(Again, I'd prefer an option, but I've given the string version here.)

Comment: As I told, I may insert code only here case // insert match statement here it is school task (not from work), according on your code I created this: `case head :: tail => if (head.isInstanceOf[List[_]]) head else tail.find(_.isInstanceOf[List[_]]).get` it works, but I am not sure if it is the best solution

Comment: @yons88 - Frank seems to have come up with an appropriate thing that meets the criteria.  This is why it's a good idea to use the homework tag!  You end up having to write solutions that would otherwise be absurd in order to demonstrate that you understand a particular point.